# How do I insert new data object in mongodb by using command line?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Like the title of the question, how do I insert a new data object through the command line ? Right now this is the code in the `mongo.js` file. When I run the command `node mongo.js password` right now, it is working as expected as shown in the last paragraph of the code(it is showing a list of all the people in the database). And this also works if I want to add manually the data by using the `person` object and saving it(as in the code that I comment out). But what if I want to add new `person` through the command-line, for example, I want to run this command,

`node mongo.js password James 21312321312`

And it adds this data object to the database? How can I make this work?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

if (process.argv.length<3) {
  console.log('give password as argument')
  process.exit(1)
}

const password = process.argv[2]

const url =
  'mongodb+srv://username:password@phonebook.axquldz.mongodb.net/personsApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

mongoose.set('strictQuery',false)
mongoose.connect(url)

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  number: Number,
})

const Persons = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema)

// const person = new Persons(
// {
// })

// person.save().then(result=> {
//   console.log('person saved!')
//   mongoose.connection.close()
// })

Persons.find({}).then(result => {
  result.forEach(person => {
    console.log(person.name + ' ' + person.number) 
  })
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

Comment: i dont think the command works because you typed `node mongo.js password`. because your `mongo` already connected without type `password`. but the things is, you need to handle the argument with creating a function like `switch` to determain what the cli do next.

Comment: @TobokSitanggang How can I do that ? Implementing conditional statements on url ?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
const url = `mongodb+srv://username:${password}@phonebook.axquldz.mongodb.net/personsApp?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
```

Note the backticks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am still figuring out how to implement it through cli